# How can I use a SQL database with my iOS app?

Tags: ios, sql, database, xcode

I currently have an iOS app that is a subscription based app.  It is a Newsstand app.  I need to be able to allow users who have a previous subscription to the print edition to have access to the iPad content.  The newspaper has a list of thier subscribers.

Is it possible to write code to check against this list to see if a user already has paid for a subscription and if so where do I go to research this?

I need to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned SQL database in the title, but not in your question.  Does the newspaper have a current SQL database?  If so, you need to determine how to tie the iPad to the subscriber.  What data does it have about the person in the database?

Comment: It has a foxpro database that I can convert to a sql.  The data base lists Name and Address

Comment: You can use PHP scripts to make the query, or use a library such as fmdb (as @KyleStew suggested)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want SQLite then fmdb is the goto library to use.
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

fmdb will greatly simplify setting up your connection to your sql file and running queries.

Comment: We've really liked using fmdb on our stuff, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against making direct database calls from any mobile device. Rather you should create a service using whatever technology you feel comfortable with (WCF, WebAPI, etc) to validate the subscription by matching the details you have stored in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unsure of a part of your question, 
as to where you want the data to be placed? local or hosted?

if you has the data in question and you just want to validate the users remotely you should properly develop some type of web service, that area is quite large

you could investigate windows azure if you do not wish to host this, or you could build a tomcat application as a web service, (connected to a sql server)

if you want to do this quick and dirty i can recommend a php site and json objects... however i have no experience with iphones and ipads, so i don't know how compatible they are with this approach

(and i really would not want to use a sql directly if i were you, that topic is just to large to explain here i'm afraid)